# How to control polling in Jenkins ClearCase plugin?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I'm polling a ClearCase stream every 10 minutes. When change is detected, my job executes build.xml.

The problem is that my job contributes an artifact to the same stream, so every job execution results in a stream update and thus causes another job execution 10 minutes later.

The fact that my build job feeds ClearCase with an artifact cannot be changed right now.

- Is there a way to ignore changes to a specific file during polling?
- Is there a way to read results of polling, understand that only a
  specific file was updated and build job can be terminated?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to ignore changes to a specific file during polling?

Not that I know of: the [polling will do a `cleartool lshistory`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15185)

> When change is detected, my job executes `build.xml`.
>   Is there a way to read results of polling, understand that only a specific file was updated and build job can be terminated?

One way would be to modify the job in order to do the `lshistory` on the right component (the one whose changes should be ignored) and check if that file is the only one returned.

```
cleartool.exe lshistory -r -since 16-may.01:56:17 -fmt "%Nd %u %e %En %Vn %o\n%c\n" -branch aStreamName -nco aVob\aComponentRootDir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UCM stream, and this is an integration stream, you could change the "polling" to only fire when someone delivers code.

That also reduces the load on the ClearCase VOB database, as lshistory is somewhat expensive.